# In MVC Authorize filter, From where roles will be picked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I am learning MVC. I want to know , from where roles will be picked up .

ex

```
        [Authorize(Roles ="admin")]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
        // GET: Search
        public ActionResult search()
        {
        return View();     
        }
        }
```

Here where should we write authorize code to make home  controller only applicable for admin.

Comment: You don't have to write any code, this is built in to MVC and triggered if you apply that attribute.

Comment: But  from where mvc will pick the roles , how it will get to know that user has admin role.

Comment: Try this tutorial. Likely store the users in a database and then define the roles using programmed functionality. If you use MVC a lot it helped me to just create a standalone application for managing roles across applications. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Comment: In the above tutorial we have defined roles , But as CodeCaster mentioned we dont have to write any code and this is built into MVC . But how MVC will get to know and from which function it will pick up the roles . Do we have to write any Session variable defining the roles or something like that ?. Please let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using ASP.NET Core, in the controller when you log in, use this code to register the login with a role attached:

```
  var role = "admin";  // or whatever role you want to use here
  var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8), false, role);
  var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then in the Global.asax.cs add this:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
  if (authCookie != null)
  {
    //get the user cookie and get the roles from it and apply them
    var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');    //note that you can use multiple roles with this
    var userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
    Context.User = userPrincipal;
  }
}
```

With that in place your Authorize attribute will pick up the role the user logged in with.

Answer (score 0):

Roles are provided by the RoleManager (or RoleProvider), [see more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/membership-and-role-provider).

For example, you can use the [`WindowsTokenRoleProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478950.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will pull roles from Windows Authentication. Or you can roll your own by inheriting `RoleProvider`:

```
public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{}
```

PS. This is for .net 4.x, `asp.net core` might be something different.